# Reverse each row in a 2D array in less than O(m * n) time

Tags: python, algorithm

Given an 2D array [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], reverse each row in less than O(m * n) time - I couldn’t solve it with the expected time complexity. I haven’t managed to figure out an algorithm that could do this in < O(m * n) - Please do comment in case you know of the solution.

Comment: Perhaps one can implement this lazily? Otherwise, I can see no avoiding the `O(n*m)` cost.

Comment: Apart from weird ideas like switching the definition of row and column I don't see a way.

Comment: Is this an exercise where your supervisor knows an answer exists, or some actual need to optimize? The description pretty much states you want to operate on NxM elements, which is itself O(NxM) even for constant operations. Is this tied to some specific implementation, where for example you can set some reverse flag for an entire row, without actually reversing elements?

Comment: Do you have to "reverse *each row* in less than O(m * n) time" or *the entire 2D array* "in less than O(m * n) time"?

Answer (score 0):

If you represent the matrix as a list of M columns, you can reverse the columns in O(M) time, because the list contains references to the columns, so you're only reversing the M references, not the M*N data elements.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Reversing the elements themselves requires O(n) operations for a list of n elements given reasonable definitions of operation. And reversing several lists requires reversing each list independently.

Now, if it is a trick question, then you can answer with tricks too. For instance, have a doubly linked list, and then reversing could be as simple as O(1) by swapping the heads and O(m) for m lists. But that is definitely not reversing the elements *themselves* within a Python list, which seems the spirit of the question, and given it is tagged as Python.